Div borders not shown outside viewport
I'm trying to simulate a table with divs + flexbox model.
If my table has too many rows/columns, I need to scroll, but when I do that, rows stop having borders. I'm not sure if this is a Chrome issue or css problem.
I have enabled all borders on cells and rows so I expect full borders shown.
Original table before scrolling right:

After scroll right:

HTML code of my table (typescript):

<div className={"flex flex-col border border-slate-500 rounded w-full overflow-scroll"}>
            {[...Array(props.rows).keys()].map((r) => {
                return (
                    <div key={r} className={clsx("text-gray-700 flex flex-row w-full", r < props.rows - 1 && "border-b border-slate-500")}>
                        {[...Array(props.columns).keys()].map((c) => {
                            return (
                                <div
                                    key={c}
                                    className={clsx("w-64 min-w-64 px-4 py-3", c < props.columns - 1 && "border-r border-slate-500")}
                                >
                                    {props.cellPainter?.(r, c)}
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>

